# glob.glob returns an empty list while reading multiple csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I am trying to concatenate multiple csv files( all placed in one folder) in a pandas dataframe. When I use glob, I get an empty list. I am am not understanding why.

Here is my code

```
    import pandas as pd

    import glob

    path=r'C:\Users\ABC\Desktop'

    files=glob.glob(path+'/*.csv') **## the code returns files as an empty list.**

   print(files)
```

Comment: what is this: `list_data-[ ]`?

Comment: sorry its list_data=[ ]

Comment: You need to edit the question so that it is accurate.

Comment: So `list_data` is empty?

Comment: yes.Its empty because "files=glob.glob(path+'/*.csv')"  returns an empty list

Comment: So why have you included all of the code after that?  It has no meaning to your question.  Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Comment: Read about [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\'
files = glob.glob(path+'*.csv')
```